# ROC curve for a perfect model, why is AUC 1.0?

Tags: classification, binary-classification

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/fundamentals-machine-learning/5-binary-classification#:%7E:text=The%20ROC%20curve%20for%20a%20perfect%20model%20would%20go%20straight%20up%20the%20TPR%20axis%20on%20the%20left%20and%20then%20across%20the%20FPR%20axis%20at%20the%20top.),

> The ROC curve for a perfect model would go straight up the TPR axis on
> the left and then across the FPR axis at the top. Since the plot area
> for the curve measures 1x1, the area under this perfect curve would be
> 1.0

Is there a more formal reasoning that explains this statement? My guess is it has something to do with summing the TPR over all possible FPR, and a perfect model should have the highest possible TPR (i.e. $1$) over all possible FPR.

Comment: I find it a bit troubling to suggest that $ROCAUC=1$ and a perfect model are synonymous. $ROCAUC$ has a theoretical maximum value of one, yes, and a model that always predicts the correct category does have $ROCAUC=1$, but a model with $ROCAUC=1$ need not have all perfect predictions according to the predictions from the `sklearn` `predict` method or a perfect score in terms of log loss or Brier score. (Perhaps I’ll demonstrate in an answer later.)

Comment: [TPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TPR) = [tournament performance rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TPR). Not. What is it then? True positive rate?

Comment: AUC = [area under curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Further_interpretations)

Comment: [FPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FPR) = [false positive rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positive_rate)?

Comment: [FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FP) = [false positive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/false_positive#Noun)?

Comment: [TN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TN) = [true negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_negative)?

Comment: [FN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FN) = [false negative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/false_negative#Noun)?

Comment: [ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROC) = [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence)? Or [receiver operating characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic)?

Comment: [Confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)

Answer (score 3):

The difficulty with ROC curves is to understand what happens when the threshold varies. There is no summing, the curve only depends on how many instances have TP/FP/TN/FN status for every threshold.

A perfect model separates the two classes perfectly, this is why it's impossible to have both FP and FN cases:

- if there are FP cases, then the threshold is too low, so there are no FN cases since the two classes are perfectly separated. The FPR is higher than 0 but the TPR is exactly 1.
- Conversely, if there are FN cases then the threshold is too high and therefore are no FP cases for the same reason. Here the TPR is lower than 1 but the FPR is exactly 0.

Example:

```
prediction value   gold status
1.0                P
0.95               P
0.92               P
0.87               P
0.82               N
0.82               N
0.82               N
0.73               N
0.67               N
0.52               N
```

In this example, the two classes are perfectly separated, i.e. all the Ps are together at the top and all the Ns are together at the bottom.

- if the threshold is higher than 0.87, then we would have FN cases but no FP case at all. This corresponds to a vertical line from (0,0) to (0,1) on the ROC curve, since FPR is 0.
- if the threshold is lower than 0.82, then we would have FP cases but no FN at all. This corresponds to a horizontal line from (0,1) to (1,1) since TPR is 1.
- if the threshold is between .82 and .87, then TPR=1 and FPR=0, this is the top left corner on the curve.

Answer (score 2):

An explanation I find more insightful is by noting the [probabilistic interpretation of AUC](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180638/how-to-derive-the-probabilistic-interpretation-of-the-auc). For any random pair of positive and negative instance, AUC is the probability that the model gives a higher score to the positive instance than the negative instance.

Given that it's a probability, obviously the highest possible value is 1.